# Import unique combination of rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, unique

I am working with a huge database which is updated every day for new entries. In order to find the duplicates we use either
checksum using the hashbytes function  and then custom remove duplicates function, or only import the unique entries using the merge function. However we encounter 
some difficulties when a set of entries is considered to be a unique business information.

E.g.:

```
date           name      adress
2013-07-01     peter     ad1
2013-07-01     peter     ad2
2013-07-01     peter     ad3
2013-07-02     peter     ad1
2013-07-02     peter     ad2
2013-07-02     peter     ad3
2013-07-04     peter     ad1
2013-07-04     peter     ad3
2013-07-05     peter     ad1
2013-07-05     peter     ad2
2013-07-05     peter     ad3
```

The desired result would be

```
date           name      adress
2013-07-01     peter     ad1
2013-07-01     peter     ad2
2013-07-01     peter     ad3
2013-07-04     peter     ad1
2013-07-04     peter     ad3
2013-07-05     peter     ad1
2013-07-05     peter     ad2
2013-07-05     peter     ad3
```

It is a simplified case, in general the import function should be able to consider a combination of several attributes 
for recognising the unique set of rows.

Comment: Please, clarify why data from 2013-07-02 should be excluded?

Comment: 2013-07-02 will be concidered as a dublicate as it contains the same business information as the previous day. However the 2013-07-04 reports the new status compared to 2013-07-01 (resp. 2013-07-02) and 2013-07-05 change in status compared to 2013-07-04  so they should be kept

Comment: So, a status is not one record but a set of records for particular date? Does order of values in `adress` column matter for particular date?

Comment: @Serg : exactly, the set of records is condidered as a business information. Order of values is not relevant

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear for me. But it's not enough concrete to provide you any advice which is not too general because general advices are obvious: a) add logic for uniting data to sets to your checksum algorythm so each record of set has the same checksum or b) use CTE in your `MERGE` statement to filter duplicates inside your data for importing. Providing your code will make possible to make more concrete advise.